# updatedb error - mktemp: too few X's in template ‘updatedb’

Tags: terminal, command-line, search

When I run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` to manually update the `locate` database, I get this error:

```bash
❯ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
Password:
mktemp: too few Xs in template ‘updatedb’
chown: missing operand after ‘nobody’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb: line 102: /var/db/locate.database: Permission denied
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you hit this is because you have the GNU `mktemp` as the first item in your path.

You can verify this by running, `type -a mktemp`. If you don't see `/usr/bin/mktemp` as the first option then that is likely your issue.

For example I have:

```bash
❯ type -a mktemp
mktemp is /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/mktemp
mktemp is /usr/bin/mktemp
```

The reason I hit this is that I have run `brew install coreutils`, and then followed the option in the caveats section:

> Commands also provided by macOS have been installed with the prefix "g".
>   If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
>   can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>      PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH

This can put the GNU `mktemp` ahead of the macOS one.

The fix is simply to stop doing that, remove the above line and just use the g-prefixed versions (e.g. `gmktemp`) when you need GNU tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the PATH with:

```
sudo env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```